# Unity integration with WinRT with interfaces and not plugins

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, windows-runtime, porting

In [this mva series](http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/training-courses/porting-unity-games-to-windows-store-and-windows-phone) 
video 3: Native Integraton at 53:00 Jaime Rodriguez says that there is an alternative to using plugins to use platform specific features of WinRT. 
That alternative is to code against an interface in unity and then implement that interface in the WinRT application. Then unity will "use magic" and connect the interface with the implementation.

Does anybody know how I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question was answered [here](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/native-integration-with-interfaces-and-not-plugins.346312/#post-2240421) in the unity forums.